# Unable to get Metadata form video using exoplayer without playback

Tags: metadata, exoplayer2.x, audiotrack

I am trying to get video metadata using exoplayer without playback as mentioned in [document](https://exoplayer.dev/retrieving-metadata.html#without-playback)

when i try to run i cannot get list of audio track and subtitle track from local video file.

```
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl);
    ListenableFuture<TrackGroupArray> trackGroupsFuture = MetadataRetriever.retrieveMetadata(this, mediaItem);
    Futures.addCallback(trackGroupsFuture, new FutureCallback<TrackGroupArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(TrackGroupArray trackGroups) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < trackGroups.length; i++){
                        String format = trackGroups.get(i).getFormat(0).sampleMimeType;
                        String lang = trackGroups.get(i).getFormat(0).language;
                        String id = trackGroups.get(i).getFormat(0).id;

                        if(format.contains("audio") && id != null && lang != null){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + lang + " " + id);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    //handleFailure(t);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
                }
            }, executor);
```

can someone help. How can I get list of tracks available in a video.

here is a sample video link https://storage.googleapis.com/jlplayer/Dolittle.mkv

for example the above sample video contains a english subtitle a hindi audio track and english audio track. So how do i extract those track ?

Comment: FYI that mkv link doesn't work anymore.  Also, it's unclear what dpenedencies and imports are required in order for you sample code to compile.   There are multiple packages (espresso-core and Firebase) that contain the missing class names ListenableFuture, and Futures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo and used below method to get video information.

```
mediaInfo.get("sample.mp4", MediaInfo.StreamKind.VIDEO, 0, "Format", MediaInfo.InfoKind.TEXT, MediaInfo.InfoKind.NAME)
```

and full solution to this question is listed in this [Unable to extract parameter from video using MediaInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70852939/unable-to-extract-parameter-from-video-using-mediainfo)